# Why is this gameloop lagging?

Tags: java, game-loop

I am completle new to Java and tried to code my own little gameloop

```
package com.luap555.main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Game implements Runnable{

private Window window;
public int width, height;
public String title;

private boolean running = false;
private Thread thread;

private BufferStrategy bs;
private Graphics g;

private int fps = 60;
private long lastTime;
private long now;
private long delta;
private long timer;
private long ticks;
private boolean initialized = false;

public Game(String title, int width, int height) {
    this.title = title;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

}

private void init() {
    window = new Window(title, width, height);
    Assets.init();
    System.out.println("Initializing finished");
    initialized = true;
}

private int x = 0;

private void tick() {
        x += 1;

}

private void render() {
    bs = window.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null) {
        window.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    g.drawImage(Assets.unten, 0 + x, 0, 700, 350, null);

    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}

private void runtick() {
        lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        tick();

        now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        delta += now - lastTime;

        try {
            Thread.sleep((delta + 1000) / fps);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        delta -= now - lastTime;
}

private void runrender() {
    render();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    init();

    if(initialized) {
        while(running) {
            runtick();
            runrender();
        }
    }

    stop();

}

public synchronized void start() {
    if(running)
        return;
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();

}

public synchronized void stop() {
    if(!running)
        return;
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

In my main Method I call the game.start() method.
But whenever I run this code, The picture´s movement is quite laggy.
I moves pretty smooth, but after every second or so there are some lags.
I think the problems are within the "runtick()"- method.
Has anyone an idea why this happens?
I hope some of you can help me ;D

Answer (score 0):

You're increasing the sleep time of the game depending on how long the the game logic takes. What you want to do is decrease the sleep depending on how long the game logic takes.

You'll also want to include the render time into your calculation (in a lot of games this can quickly become larger than the game logic time). Try something like this:

```
long delta, end, start = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (running) {
    runtick();
    runrender();

    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    delta = (end - start);
    Thread.sleep((1000 / fps) - delta);
    start = end;
}
```

If you ever find that `delta` becomes larger than the tick interval `(1000 / fps)` than you should log some warnings and to mitigate you can run multiple game logic ticks per one render tick to allow the game logic to catch up with the animation.

Comment: @Luap555 you can remove the line `start = end;` if you're going to reassign `start` at the beginning of the while loop. I added in `start = end;` to reduce the amount of calls to `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, if I add `if(delta > (1000 / fps)` , what should this if-statement do? Because just an error warning doesn´t help, I guess. At the moment the picture still doesn´t move completele smooth.

Comment: If this happens you probably need to reduce the FPS. As a mitigation to the issue (a workaround really... this has trade-offs) is to run extra "ticks" for the game logic. `while(delta > (1000 / fps)) {runtick(); delta -= (1000 / fps);}`